# What are the algorithm details of FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, implementation-details

The Help page of `FindRoot` says: "by default, `FindRoot` uses Newton's method (Newton-Raphson) to solve a nonlinear system". But I still have the following puzzles:

1. How will the Jacobian be calculated in each iteration: symbolically or using finite difference approximation only?
2. Is there any damping method of the step being used when the Jacobian at any step is invertible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can control how the Jacobian is calculated via [the `Jacobian` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html#58854240):

```
Grid[Module[{s = 0, e = 0}, 
    {#, 
     FindRoot[ArcTan[1000 Cos[x]], {x, 1}, StepMonitor :> s++, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> e++, Jacobian -> #, Method -> {"Newton"}],
     "Steps" -> s, 
     "Evaluations" -> e
    }] & /@ {"Symbolic", "FiniteDifference"}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Note the `Sparse` suboption of this option described on the linked Documentation page (see also [this tutorial page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSpecifyingDerivatives.html) for additional examples of use), it works both with `"Symbolic"` and `"FiniteDifference"` methods. [The `DampingFactor` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html#139953229) may be also of help.

You can also find useful [this MathGroups answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/K2XeMympaVg/3HgVtFf63BQJ) by Oliver Ruebenkoenig (Wolfram Research).

Comment: Thank you very much! that is what I need!

Comment: @LCFactorization There's some additional info [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html) (3rd and 4th sections), mostly about how the Jacobian is updated.