# What are the hidden specifications for FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, implementation-details

The Help page of `FindRoot` says:

> "by default, FindRoot uses Newton's method (Newton-Raphson) to solve a
>   nonlinear system"

(or a nonlinear equation I suppose).
Nevertheless, there is something hidden for me in the `FindRoot` command. Consider the function

```
f[x]:=Exp[1 - x] - 1,
```

whose Newton iteration function is

```
Nf[x_]:=E^(-1 + x) (-1 + E^(1 - x)) + x
```

Iterating with this function using `NestList` you obtain the sequence of values produced by Newton's method. The Newton method for large values of the initial guess presents slow convergence for this problem.Taking $x_0=10$ we get:

```
NestList[Nf, 10., 8]
(* {10., -8092.08, -8091.08, -8090.08, -8089.08, -8088.08, -8087.08, -8086.08, -8085.08} *)
```

where we can see the slow convergence. A plot of the function `Nf[x]` helps to understand the behaviour of the method.
But taking

```
Module[{s = 0, e = 0}, {FindRoot[f[x], {x, 10.}, StepMonitor :> s++, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> e++], "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}]
```

produces

```
{{x -> 1.}, "Steps" -> 7, "Evaluations" -> 11}
```

needing only 7 steps to get the solution $x=1$. Why `FindRoot` produces this result?. Obviously, `FindRoot` is not using the standard Newton's method, isn't it?
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: See  [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37804/what-are-the-algorithm-details-of-findroot) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/K2XeMympaVg/3HgVtFf63BQJ)

Answer (score 10):

By default `FindRoot` uses the `"LineSearch"` method of step control as described in the tutorial [`tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationLineSearchMethods`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationLineSearchMethods.html).  The default settings are

```
FindRoot[Exp[1 - x] - 1, {x, 10.},
 Method -> {"Newton", 
   "StepControl" -> {"LineSearch", "CurvatureFactor" -> Automatic, 
     "DecreaseFactor" -> 1/10000, "MaxRelativeStepSize" -> 10,  Method -> Automatic}}]
```

To get Newton's method more or less exactly, use no step control. However, `FindRoot` still limits the maximum step size (the first step in the case below is truncated to `x == -100.`):

```
Module[{s = 0, e = 0},
 {FindRoot[Exp[1 - x] - 1, {x, 10.}, 
   Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}, StepMonitor :> s++, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> e++], "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

```
(*  {{x -> -1.07713}, "Steps" -> 100, "Evaluations" -> 101}  *)
```

You can use the options

```
StepMonitor :> Print[{x}], EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]
```

to monitor the steps and evaluations.  Or you can use `FindRootPlot` in the `` "Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`" `` package.  (Look carefully for the yellow dots denoting an evaluation that is not a step.)

```
Needs["Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`"]

FindRootPlot[Exp[1 - x] - 1, {x, 10.}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FindRootPlot[Exp[1 - x] - 1, {x, 10.}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Put another way: `FindRoot[]` is using a *damped* version of Newton-Raphson, for without the damping, bad choices of starting values will more often result in divergence. The damping makes the iterations less likely to go wild.